# Download button does not work please help

Tags: android

Ok so I have my app 90% built everything works but my download button. I have been stuck on this for days now so if anyone could help a guy out with something that will work for this. my files are .pkg and I feed the filename from a xml file and here is my buttons code but I dont know what I am doing wrong here. It just does nothing upon clicking it. The appUrl is my file name from the xml file

```
Button b_get_book = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b_get_book.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {              
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         try {
                                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                URL u = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/" + appUrl);
                                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                c.setDoOutput(true);
                                c.connect();
                                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(root, appUrl));

                                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int len1 = 0;
                                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                                }
                                f.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("Downloader", e.getMessage());
                            }  
                    }
           });
```

Any help would be great I have been pulling my hair out over this. I make a pretty complex app and its the easy thing that gets me...... go figure. if anyone can help me out with some working code from a button that would be awesome. even better if it has a progress bar for the downloads. that is my next task after getting the actual download working. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to log something at the beginning of the listener so you know that it really does anything. You should also think about not to do the download on the UI thread, this will block you app till the download finishes.

Answer (score 0):

First idea is that you get an IOException when trying to create a file. If I were you I would, first of all, move the code which is currently in your try-catch clause to somewhere else, and test it. Then when it's working well I would just call it from within try-catch.

Also, I would recommend **against** running such long operations in GUI thread - that makes your app non-responsive to user input. The following approach is most recommended:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                  @Override
                  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                      try {
                        /* your code here*/
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Downloader", e.getMessage());
                      }  
                  }
               }.execute();
        }
```